# Call www in class in Unity3d

Tags: client-server, unity-game-engine

I have some method to comunity with server, But when i use www in a function in class -> it doesn't run , to check i use www like with code i use in class --> it run.. I don't know what's happening, please help me!

Comment: Can you provide some example code for us to review?

Comment: i have a class to define a model with set get methods. i want to call webservice in this class when i call set method. because model class is not a subclass of monobehaviour, so it doesn't have `WWW` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class that does inherit MonoBehaviour, then call that.

Example of Javascript(unity) way
    // Get the latest webcam shot from outside "Friday's" in Times Square
    var url = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";
    function Start () {
         // Start a download of the given URL
        var www : WWW = new WWW (url);

```
    // Wait for download to complete
    yield www;

    // assign texture
    renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
}
```

[EDIT] Example of C# way

```
/// Gets the response.
/// 
/// <param name="StrURL">The URL.
/// HTML source
public string GetResponse(string StrURL)
{
    string strReturn = "";
    HttpWebRequest objRequest = null;
    IAsyncResult ar = null;
    HttpWebResponse objResponse = null;
    StreamReader objs = null;
    try
    {

        objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(StrURL);
        ar = objRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetScrapingResponse),     objRequest);

        //// Wait for request to complete
        ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000 * 60, true);
        if (objRequest.HaveResponse == false)
        {
            throw new Exception("No Response!!!");
        }

        objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.EndGetResponse(ar);
        objs = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
        strReturn = objs.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw exp;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (objResponse != null)
        objResponse.Close();
        objRequest = null;
        ar = null;
        objResponse = null;
        objs = null;
    }
    return strReturn;
}

/// Gets the scraping response.
///
/// <param name="result">The result.
protected void GetScrapingResponse(IAsyncResult result)
{
    //here you will need to cast/parse the response into what ever type you require e.g. a texture, an xml file, an asset bundle, ect.
}
```

Call like so

```
GetResponse('http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg');
```

[Edit]

Basicly Javascript files in Unity automatically inherit from MonoBehavior.

If you are absolutly certain you cant/wont just create  a class that inherits monobehaviour (Example #1) to do the work for you, then your asking how to do a normal XMLHttpRequest to a url.

Javascript Example here:

```
var xmlHttp = null;

function GetServerInfo()
{
    var Url = "http://localhost";

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", Url, true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
}

function ProcessRequest() 
{
    if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 ) 
    {
        if ( xmlHttp.responseText == "Not found" ) 
        {

        }
        else
        {
            var info = eval ( "(" + xmlHttp.responseText + ")" );
            //Here is where it will get super tricky. You will need to parse these objects into unity objects.
        }                    
    }
}
```

The really complicated part of this is you will need to parse your http response into unity objects...

Comment: thank u so much, but i want to call a request in model class [it isn't  monobehaviour] it just a normal class. could u give me some ideas.

Comment: thanks for your enthusiasm . Could I use HttpWebResponse with js script. Because i tried to call HttpWebResponse in js script but it not successful [I had already import system.net]. could u call it in js script

Comment: @HuyTran youre welcome. the first example was how to do it in javascript, the second was how to do it in C# that does not inherit from monobehaviour. Just check that you have added the code to the correct file type .js/.cs

Comment: because my code defined a model in js script.So, i must call HttpWebResponse in this script to community with server. Your first example you call WWW in monobehaviour subclass but I must to call it in normal model class [not monobehaviour subclass] coded by js script .. I tested with second example --> it ran, I tried to use it in my js script --> It informed no HttpWebResponse support in js.

Comment: Yeah the second example is C# so it will no work in Js. If you post some code ill be able to help you more.

[I'll update my post]

Comment: You’re very welcome. Mind marking my answer as 'correct' Cheers :)